Appropriateness of lasers for alien plant control
In my science fiction setting, it is the tail end of the twenty-first century, and most scientific fields and engineering disciplines have advanced substantially. There has been further developments in laser technology, fueled by improvements in materials science and batteries (There are commercially available batteries with comparable energy density to gasoline), and laser weapons were widely deployed among current militaries for anti-drone and missile applications. However, the known issues with laser weapons (cooling issues and energy) have prevented anti personnel deployment.
However, humanity has recently come under attack. A directed panspermia mission from an unknown nearby civilization has implanted a new and very hostile ecosystem into the Sol System, similar to The War Against the Chtorr.
While I'm not going to go in depth into the details of the ecology here, part of the invasion includes a wide variety of toxic and carnivorous plants that have a habit of cropping up in inhabited areas and ensnaring and digesting people. I wondered whether this is a rare situation where lasers could be better than the alternative.
What the military needs is a multipurpose, man-portable tool that can be used by soldiers to perform weeding duty and safely destroy toxic plant growths at a distance, as well as cut out soldiers trapped in carnivorous plants without getting close and being eaten themselves.
I think that this situation could mitigate many of the disadvantage of handheld laser anything. The fact that the targets, plants, would be stationary, means that a lower power laser could be used for cutting and weeding. This would mean less cooling and fewer batteries necessary to run the laser. My understanding is phased-array optics could give precise control over the beam. But is my understanding of the science correct? Would lasers be the best choice for this situation?
EDIT
It seems that per usual in science fiction, this is not a justifiable application for laser weaponry. The multiple issues JBH mentioned plus the much lower cost of a pole saw means the laser backpack will be removed from the setting. From a narrative perspective, this might be a good thing. Having manual control over the cutting implement getting your friend out of a plant makes the story more exciting then if the targeting is done via computer.

We do not yet have a policy for "review my idea" questions, so this question suffers for not having a specific problem to solve (required by Stack Exchange). Let's throw some ideas at you, though. (a) Lasers are intentionally a narrow beam of light. Using them like a flamethrower is a wide beam of light, which seriously undermines their value. (b) You're still dealing with photons. Do your plants hate visible spectrum photons? If not, lasers aren't the best choice. Microwaves would likely be better. (*Continued*)

... (c) Energy, unlike spewed flamable fluid or gas, isn't affected very much by gravity, atmospherics, or a diminishing fuel source. In other words, flamethrowers have a range limit, but your lasers kinda don't. More accurately, the range is so much greater that you really care about what's behind the plant. Anything that would kill the plant would hurt or kill anyone standing within a couple of hundred feet behind it. This means your energy-based solution can only be used to sweep the ground or other hard surfaces without consequences. (Not a bad thing for a story, though.) ...

... Which brings us to the fact that you're kinda putting the cart before the horse. How have you designed your plants? What allows them to survive on Earth's surface? What weaknesses to they have that humans can exploit? In other words, if you want to use lasers, then you should be asking us for help designing your plants, not the other way around.

Thanks for engaging on this. For the design of the carnivorous plants, I took heavy inspiration from earth biology. I figured that billions of years of evolution would do a better job than my few hundred cubic centimeters of brain.

The most common plants consist of mobile stems with pigmentation designed to blend into the surfaces they are seeded on. They would ambush humans, wrap around them, and try to inject toxins in their body to kill them. Think similar to a sundew.

But the other big application of this device is regular weed control. There are large variety of plants that are designed to break down infrastructure like roads, powerlines, and buildings. They need to be cleared out without damaging the stuff they have attached to.

Lasers with phased-array optics could steer the beam fairly precisely around ensnared people to cut off, stems or directly onto damaging plants.

When adding detail to your question, please remember to [edit] your post with the answers and not put them into comments. Never trust that people will read through all the comments. No matter how narrow you want the beam, the beam itself must be broad enough to kill the entire plant - not just cut it to pieces. The greater the spread of the beam, the greater the potential of damaging what's behind the plant. Visible light isn't damaging to Earth-capable biology, so your goal must be to burn the plants. If you can burn a plant, you'll burn people, buildings, and start fires.

Please keep in mind that you're kinda screwed in either direction with a laser. A broad beam that will burn but not cut the plant will burn things around the plant. A narrow beam that can cut the plant will cut what's behind it. This isn't a bad thing for a story (bullets can go through people, after all) as collateral damage due to the immediacy of the solution is anticipated. I'm just pointing out the good and bad of what you're doing: but to be honest, it realy sounds like you're married to lasers and need help designing the plants.

One last thing: This solution is really a non-starter. people use flame burners to control weeds around the world, but all they're doing is controlling the weeds today. They're not killing the weeds. The technique is used to quickly clear fields or ditches, etc. Killing weeds requires poison, not heat. In that regard a microwave emitter pointed at the roots would be more believable than a laser-based flame thrower.

Absolutely you can use lasers for weed control, in fact, here's a laser weeder you can actually buy that does 100'000 weeds an hour! - not quite man-portable, but anyone waging interstellar war is likely to have (at least a little bit) more advanced tech

Question: why would you not use a Flamethrower? Is there a story reason? Are you just wanting Lasers because Rule of Cool? Is there a story reason for needing Lasers? I would like a little more info before answering.

It's going to be hard to beat the Pointy Stick Mk3 (the motorized pole saw) for medium range plant cutting. Lasers with AI targeting might do a good job of identifying and zapping unwanted seedlings, though.

Sorry, it took me a bit to absorb your commentary, JBH

Lasers are being used to clear leaves off of railroad tracks as a real world use of lasers for plant control.

This is already happening here. Have a look at the Mosquito Laser. If the targeting mechanism becomes cheap enough, then this can deny territory such as inside a house to mosquitoes. This is not the same as attacking them in open country, but it does make a lot of sense in the home, where you do not want the cumulative risks of using pesticides.
The argument against lasers is one of scale. You can use them to zap mosquitoes. You could make a bigger version to protect you against lions, but it would not be the best solution. The general principle of using some sort of vision model to recognise the target, and then organising some mechanical attack still holds. But the defence might be drones with guns or nets rather than using a laser. For your plants, you would probably want something mechanical that could take out the roots, and burn any seeds.

Lasers would be inefficient
There are many ways your could make lasers more viable. There's automatic machines that can drive over fields, recognise weeds and spray only those with toxins. I think I remember an UV variant as well, which is not dissimilar to a laser.
You could have small drones fly around with lasers, heat up key features of the plant to set them on fire or burn away important parts.
However, this might not he an effective method for many plants. You likely want to eradicate the whole plant. Plants live for a great part underground with their roots. This not only gathers some nutrition and water, it is also a storage of energy. Many plants will die if you mess with the above ground portion, but there's many that will live. The Japanese Knotweed comes to mind, where I read that shredding the whole plant, root and stem, can cause many of the individual shredded pieces to start growing again.
That means if you burn just the top portion, the bottom portion could happily live on, spread and regrow. Worse, as they consume live matter they might not rely on something above ground at all. It could just grow a shallow basin in the ground, fill the air with intoxicating aerosols, have people fall into the basin and down, to be consumed over time by the stuff in the basin. It could be mostly covered by the liquid it makes, making you able to attack precious little of the plant.
What would be most effective? Natural enemies. Things that can effectively eat it. Things that are parasites and leech the plants dry. You can bioengineer one or a few (micro) organisms that suppress or eradicate the plants effectively. They will naturally spread, making it easier to get all in an area. Once in a while you spread them around yourself to make sure an area is safe. This way nothing can grow in far enough to be a threat.
There is evolution or further bioengineering of the plants? You have an easier time breaking their new bio defences than they have creating them. If evolution of your own organisms doesn't do it for you.

The problem here is that using foreign species to combat foreign species has historically created more problems than it has solved.
